# Vector to populate matrix

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

This is my input Excel:

```
L1  2   1
L1  1   2
L2  1   3
L3  1   1
L4  1   1
```

I want output like this on another sheet:

```
    L1  L2  L3  L4
1   2       1   1
2   1           
3       1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: actualy my domain is c#. m new to VBA

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the first and third values in each row in the input give the column and row for the output? If so, could you ever have two lines of data in the input that referred to the same column and row in the output?

Comment: I second @KarolMarianSłuszniak's suggestion.  Is there a specific reason you aren't just using a Pivot Table? This is exactly the sort of situation they are intended for.

Comment: I want put 2nd column values into matrix based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

[image: SO26057608 example]

Ensure that your columns are labelled, select them and click on INSERT > Tables - PivotTable.

Answer (score 2):

I include this as an alternative to using a pivot table. One or other may be more useful/convenient depending on context.

1. Enter the column headers L1-L4 and the row headers 1-3 into sheet 2 manually.
2. Then enter the following array formula in `sheet2!b2` using
   `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` and copy it down and across:

   ```
   =SUM((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5=B$1)\*(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5=$A2)\*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5))
   ```

Set the number format for the cells to `#` (Format cells | Number tab | Custom and enter Type as `#`) to make any zeroes appear as blanks.

[image]

Comment: It's not working Mr.Tom Sharpe. The pivot table is working. if you know exact formula or Macro code(VBA) its very helpful.

Comment: BALA s did you definitely put the formula in as an array formula holding down Ctrl & Shift then pressing Enter so that it appeared with curly brackets as in the screenshot? Also I'm assuming your data is in Sheet 1 exactly as in your question, with no headers. It was fine when I tested it.